# Cant seem to make a regex for a specific case

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, node.js

I' working with nodes and I need to apply a UNIX-type of grep command to a body response I'm getting after an HTTP GET. 
Here is the incoming text (body variable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <om2m:discovery xmlns:om2m="http://uri.etsi.org/m2m" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
    <om2m:matchSize>65</om2m:matchSize>
    <om2m:discoveryURI>
        <reference>gscl</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/mgmtObjs</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/mgmtObjs</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/accessRights</reference>
        <reference>gscl/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/groups</reference>
        <reference>gscl/groups/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/containers</reference>
        <reference>gscl/containers/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/accessRights/AR_ADMIN</reference>
        <reference>gscl/accessRights/AR_ADMIN/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/mgmtObjs</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/accessRights</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/groups</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/groups/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/containers</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/containers/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/attachedDevices</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/attachedDevices/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/notificationChannels</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/mgmtObjs</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/m2mPocs</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/accessRights</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/groups</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/groups/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/notificationChannels</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR </reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/CI_23326802</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/CI_566628946</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/contentInstances</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/CI_285448423</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/contentInstances</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/subscriptions</reference>
        <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/CI_395775165</reference>
    </om2m:discoveryURI> </om2m:discovery>
```

From that text, I need to extract the ID between *applications* and *containers*, which, in this case, equals **98191axla**. I've attempted to do so using the match method:

```
var searchFor="\s<reference>gscl\/applications\.\d\/DATA\/contentInstances\/subscriptions<\/reference>";
      console.log("Looking for:"); console.log(searchFor);
      var found = body.match(searchFor);
```

Which always returns -1. I've never worked with regex before, so I had to try different things...none of them have worked.
Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!
(btw, I know it is a xml representation, but it is not a complex one with very different children, so I thought manipulating the text would be easier...)

Comment: [You cant/shouldnt try to parse xml/html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/560593), instead use something that is made to actually parse the language. For instance there is a [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml2js) module you can import and use

Comment: I've tried a few libs (xml2js, xmldoc and libxmljs), but I just thought that for this particular application and xml representation, regex would be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var re = /<reference>gscl\/applications\/(\w+)\/containers\/DATA\/congtentInstances\/subscriptions<\/reference>/;
var m = str.match(re);
if (m) console.log(m[1]);
```

Note that a regexp object is declared between slashes (without enclosing the pattern between quotes).

The pattern use the `\w` [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) that contains ascii digits and letters (and the underscore). This class is followed by the [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` that means *one or more*.
Finally, to isolate the substring you need, a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is used.

Comment: That is awesome. I now understand what I was doing wrong... Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Regex expert, but the following seems to work on this data set.

```js
//Your data simulated. 
var data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML; 

var myRegexp = /\/applications\/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)\/containers/g;

//Group iteration from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/402706
var match = myRegexp.exec(data);
while (match != null) {
    //write out each id that was found
    console.log(match[1]);
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
    match = myRegexp.exec(data);
}
```

```html
<script type='text' id='data'>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <om2m:discovery xmlns:om2m="http://uri.etsi.org/m2m" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
        <om2m:matchSize>65</om2m:matchSize>
        <om2m:discoveryURI>
            <reference>gscl</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/mgmtObjs</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/mgmtObjs</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/accessRights</reference>
            <reference>gscl/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/groups</reference>
            <reference>gscl/groups/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/containers</reference>
            <reference>gscl/containers/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/accessRights/AR_ADMIN</reference>
            <reference>gscl/accessRights/AR_ADMIN/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/mgmtObjs</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/applications/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/accessRights</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/groups</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/groups/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/containers</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/containers/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/attachedDevices</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/attachedDevices/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/notificationChannels</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/mgmtObjs</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/mgmtObjs/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/scls/nscl/m2mPocs</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/accessRights</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/accessRights/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/groups</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/groups/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/notificationChannels</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR </reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/CI_23326802</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/CI_566628946</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/contentInstances</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/SENSOR/contentInstances/CI_285448423</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/contentInstances</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/contentInstances/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_360523761/subscriptions</reference>
            <reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/DATA/contentInstances/CI_395775165</reference>
        </om2m:discoveryURI> </om2m:discovery>
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Will definitely use this, as it is simple to tweak to work better for different unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var data = '<reference>gscl/applications/98191axla/containers/CONT_81747241</reference>';

console.log(data.match(/\/applications\/([^]+)(?=\/containers)/i)[1]);
```

Basically, the parentheses are going to *capture* the text between `/applications/` and `/containers`

Comment: I ended up using Casimir's, but thanks a lot for the quick reply!